# 24h Format in Timepicker

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a TimePicker and changed the Format to "HH:mm" to disable the AM-PM system. However, the picker still shows AM and PM instead of numbers from 00:00 to 23:59.

```
<TimePicker Time="13:00" Format="HH:mm"/>
```

[Foto of iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEGGf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use custom renderer to achieve this effect :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TimePicker), typeof(MyTimePickerRenderer))]
namespace App18.iOS
{
   class MyTimePickerRenderer:TimePickerRenderer
     {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
         {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           if (Control != null)
             {
               UIDatePicker picker = Control.InputView as UIDatePicker;
               picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Time;
               NSLocale locale = new NSLocale("en_GB");
               picker.Locale = locale;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

format that you are specifying only means how user will see the value he has selected.
if you want to change the way it looks in the control itself you will have to implement custom renderer for the TimePicker. I believe this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/time-picker-as-24-hours-format-in-xamarin-forms/) can help you in creating the custom renderer.